# Representing a positive $x$ with a generating function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

If we want to find the integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ such that $x_1$ is positive using a generating function.

We would first make the parentheses for each $x_i$, for $x_{2,3}$ it would be the standard: $(1+x+x^2...)$ but how can we represent the positive part of $x_1$?

Comment: Why not $(x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rule out the possibility $x_1=0$; that’s represented by an exponent of $0$, so you need to leave off the $x^0=1$ term. The factor corresponding to $x_1$ should therefore be

$$x+x^2+x^3+\ldots=x(1+x+x^2+\ldots)\;.$$

Comment: Oh I see. So if the restriction was $x_1$ is negative, then it would be $-(x+x^2+x^3...) $?

Comment: @kuhaku: No, then it would a different kind of problem altogether. In fact there would then be infinitely many solutions, so it would be a nonsensical problem. If the restriction were that $x_1$ is even, it would be $1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\ldots$.

Comment: What do you mean by solutions? Isn't $1+x+x^2+…= \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ also infinite?

Comment: @kuhaku: I mean integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ such that $x_1<0$: there are infinitely many of them, so there’s no formula for counting them. Don’t confuse the infinite series with the thing that its coefficients are counting.